# QTP not able to fetch Text property when the Text is too large

Tags: automation, qtp

I'm facing an issue in which QTP is not fetching text property of a WinObject when the Text is too large. In other cases it's properly fetching the Text property.

Note: It's not fetching Text property in Object Spy as well as at run time using method GetROProperty.

See the below screen print in which it's working fine because the Text is not too large.
[image: Not Fetching Text Property - With Request Tab]

But in Response Tab the text is too large & so it's not able to fetch the Text property. See the below screen print.

[image: Fetching Text Property]

Comment: Did you find the limit at which this problem starts to appear?

Comment: Do you want to verify all this text?
Yes, looking at text present in "Response Tab" we can guess that QTP
 has limitation to fetch long text.You should use alternate method like copying this data to some txt then verify it

Answer (score 0):

QTP had this limitation in version 9.0 on text length to be about 16,383 characters.
I am not sure whether this limitation exists in current versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across this recently, to read all text from WinObject use the following piece of code (this worked for me),

> bLargetext=Parent().Child().WinObject("objectname").Object.Document.text